# Ruby: Avoiding infinite loop in an array that doubles each number

Tags: ruby

So there is an infinte loop here, but I'm not seeing it.

```
# Return an array that doubles each number
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.each do |number|
  numbers << number * 2
end
puts numbers
```

I understand there are shorter ways to do this, but I am learning so it's all written out more explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding elements to an array while iterating over that array. It's [therefore impossible to reach the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNfkZ.jpg).

What you need to do is use the `map` function:

```
numbers.map! do |n|
  n * 2
end
```

That updates each entry in place with its value times two.

If you're looking to add on a single set of doubled numbers:

```
numbers += numbers.map do |n|
  n * 2
end
```

That adds on a copy of the array that's been doubled.

**Edit:** Instead of using `map`, for academic illustration purposes, you can try using a copy with `dup`:

```
numbers.dup.each do |n|
  numbers << n * 2
end
```

You can also iterate over it sequentially:

```
numbers.each_index do |i|
  numbers << numbers[i] * 2
end
```

These are all far less efficient and are much harder to read than the `map` version.

Comment: If i didn't know the map function, how would I go about solving this infinite loop to make return array with doubled numbers?

Comment: That's a big hypothetical, as a lot of the power of Ruby comes from its core library. I've added an edit.

Comment: Mark answers that solve the problem as accepted. This helps other people in the same situation find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cant see the process since this infinity lasts forever and never reaches your `puts numbers` statement. Thats why you cant see it in the console.

Try something like:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.each do |number|
  numbers << number * 2
  puts numbers
end
```

To see your pc going mad :)

Answer (score 0):

by pushing the doubled value in the array you are increasing the array size each time by 1. hence infinite loop is occurring. I think what you really want to do is

```
numbers.each do |num|
  puts num *2
end
```

Comment: This just prints them, it doesn't add them to the array.

Answer (score 0):

> Return an array that doubles each number

Assuming you don't want to use `map`, you can use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.each_with_object([]) { |n, o| o << n + n }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentioned the obvious answer, here it is :

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
double_numbers = []
numbers.each do |number|
  double_numbers << number * 2
end
p double_numbers
# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

This would be the way to do it if you didn't know about `map` or `map!`. Note that you iterate on one array and create another one in order to avoid messing with the `each` loop.